# Screen tearing with optimus laptop on Xorg on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, xorg, nvidia-optimus, 22.04

I am running ubuntu 22.04 (kernel version 5.17) on my optimus laptop with an nvidia 3060 and a intel i9.
I am using the new 510 drivers and `nvidia-prime` to select my gpu. My monitor is hiDpi, so I need fractional scaling to actually read words on screen

The problem I have been having is that terrible screen tearing that happens on `intel`, `on-demand`, and `nvidia` when using `Xorg` with fractional scaling. (It's okay when I run `wayland`, but the fractional scaling there is so blurry)

Here are the things I tried and didn't work.

1. Creating a `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf` file and writing recommended settings.
2. Adding `options nvidia-drm modeset=1` to `/lib/modprobe.d/nvidia-graphics-drivers.conf` and running `sudo update-initramfs -u`
3. Reinstalling my nvidia drivers